# Out of Stock Split Variant Dropdown

Tags: shopify

I'm looking to disable out of stock variants with split variant dropdowns. Though, even when the variant is unavailable, it's showing as available in the code. Is there something I'm missing to check the variant is out of stock?

```html
<form action="/cart/add" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" data-cart-submit>
    <select id="variant-select" name="id">
        {% for variant in product.variants %}
            {% if variant.available %}
                <option value="{{variant.id}}" 
                    {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected {%endif %}>
                    {{ variant.title }}
                </option>
            {% else %}
                <option value="{{variant.id}}" disabled="disabled">{{ variant.title }} - sold out!</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

The Javascript running this code is:

```js
{% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
    <script>
        function selectCallback(variant, selector) {
        // This is where you would put any code that you want to run when the variant changes.
        }

        var variantIdFieldIdentifier = 'variant-select';
        new Shopify.OptionSelectors(variantIdFieldIdentifier, { 
            // Product object required to know how options map to variants...
            product: {{ product | json }},
            // Function to do any interesting stuff (eg: update price field, image, etc) when selections change... 
            onVariantSelected: selectCallback,
            // When true, will update the URL to be a direct link to the currently-selected variant...
            enableHistoryState: true
        })
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

I'm wanting to disable options if the variant is unavailable.

Comment: I tried this code and it seems to work fine. The out of stock variant is disabled, as you'd expect.

Comment: Have you checked the `variant.inventory_policy` to see if they're available for sale even when out of stock?